# ns: Avg: can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"

Tags: file, tcl, ns2

This a code to simulate an MM1 queue server (not really an important fact). I'm trying to get the average value to the number of packets in the queue for each run. Given that I read the value of lambda from a file, modify it, save the new modified value of it in the file again, and run the simulation with current value of lambda:

```
#Create a simulator object
set ns [new Simulator]

global ns tracefile namf Qsize Qbw Qlost Qmon Avgvals InterArrivalTime lambda

   proc readfile {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f
    return $data
}
proc writefile {filename data} {
    set f [open $filename w]
    puts -nonewline $f $data
    close $f
}


#Define different colors for data flow (for NAM)
$ns color 1 Blue

#Open the NAM trace file
set namf [open QMM1.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namf

set Qsize [open Qsize.tr w]
set Qbw   [open Qbw.tr   w]
set Qlost [open Qlost.tr w]   
set Avgvals [open Avgvals.tr a+]
set tracefile [open out.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tracefile


#set lambda and Mu

set mu     1100.0

catch {set lambda [readfile LamdaValue.tr]}
set lambda [expr {$lambda + 100.0}]
writefile LamdaValue.tr $lambda


#Create the Node to generate the traffic Queue and Server
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]

# Since packet sizes will be rounded to an integer
# number of bytes, we should have large packets and
# to have small rounding errors, and so we take large bandwidth

#Create link between the two nodes
set link [$ns simplex-link $n1 $n2 100kb 0ms DropTail]

#Monitor the queue for link (n1-n2) for nam
$ns simplex-link-op $n1 $n2 queuePos 0.5


#set up a large Queue capacity (n1-n2)
$ns queue-limit $n1 $n2 100000

# generate random interarrival times and packet sizes

#Set arrivals to be exponential
set InterArrivalTime [new RandomVariable/Exponential]

#Avg=1/lambda
#$InterArrivalTime set avg_ [expr 1/$lambda]


set pktSize [new RandomVariable/Exponential]
$pktSize set avg_ [expr 100000.0/(8*$mu)]

#Set src to use UDP
set src [new Agent/UDP]
$src set fid_ 1
$ns attach-agent $n1 $src

# queue monitoring, write statistics to queueStat
set Qmon [$ns monitor-queue $n1 $n2 [open queueStat.out w] 0.1]
$link queue-sample-timeout


proc record {} {
global ns Qmon Qsize Qbw Qlost n1 n2 Avgvals lambda
set time 0.05
set now [$ns now]

# print in the file $Qsize the current queue size
# print in the file $Qbw the current used bandwidth
# print in the file $Qlost the loss rate

$Qmon instvar parrivals_ pdepartures_ bdrops_ bdepartures_ pdrops_ 
puts $Qsize "[expr $parrivals_-$pdepartures_-$pdrops_]"
puts $Qbw   "$now [expr $bdepartures_*8/1024/$time]"
set bdepartures_ 0                                
puts $Qlost "$now [expr $pdrops_/$time]"
$ns at [expr $now+$time] "record"
}   


proc finish {} {
    global ns tracefile namf Qsize Qbw Qlost Qmon
    $ns flush-trace 
    #Close the NAM trace file
    close $namf
    close $Qsize
    close $Qbw
    close $Qlost
    close $tracefile   
    #Execute NAM on the trace file
    #exec ./nam QMM1.nam & 
    exit 0 
} 

proc sendpacket {} {
    global ns src InterArrivalTime pktSize 
    set time [$ns now]
    $ns at [expr $time + [$InterArrivalTime value]] "sendpacket"
    set bytes [expr round ([$pktSize value])]
    $src send $bytes
}



proc Avg {} {
global ns Qmon Qsize Qbw Qlost n1 n2 Avgvals lambda

set sum 0.0
set c 1

set fid [open Qsize.tr r]
  set txt [read $fid]
  close $fid

  foreach {x} $txt {
    set sum [expr {$sum + $x}]
    incr c 1
  }


 set avg [expr $sum/$c]
puts $Avgvals "$lambda $avg"

}

set sink [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n2 $sink
$ns connect $src $sink

proc repeatSim {} {
        global lambda
        if {$lambda < 1002} {
        exec ./ns QMM1.tcl &
        }
 }


    #Avg=1/lambda
    $InterArrivalTime set avg_ [expr 1/$lambda]
    puts "Lambda = $lambda"
        puts "Mu = $mu"
    $ns at 0.0 "record"
    $ns at 0.0001 "sendpacket"
    $ns at 1000.0 "Avg"
    $ns at 1000.0 "repeatSim"

#Run the simulation
$ns run
```

The problem is that it does the first three self calls from :

```
proc repeatSim {} {
        global lambda
        if {$lambda < 1002} {
        exec ./ns QMM1.tcl &
        }
}
```

Then it gives the error in the title.
The full error statement is:

```
ns: Avg: can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
    while executing
 "expr {$sum + $x}"
    (procedure "Avg" line 12)
    invoked from within
"Avg"
```

I have tried several manipulations in the code but the error still shows in the same way.
Can you tell what the problem is?

Comment: I am no expert in `ns2`. But, looking at the error message you got, it seems like the value of `x` read from the file might be a alphabet or special character instead of numerical value. You have initialized `sum` as 0.0. So, odd man out which obviously pointing the problem with `x`. Can you check that ?

Comment: Do you really need to post all that code to show us the problem? Please edit your question and remove anything that does not directly affect the problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Walkthrough of How To Debug Your code

Let's look at that error message more carefully.

```
ns: Avg: can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"
    while executing
"expr {$sum + $x}"
    (procedure "Avg" line 12)
    invoked from within
"Avg"
```

It says that one of the arguments to the `+` operator is not a number, and this was in the calling of `expr {$sum + $x}` on the 12th line of a procedure called `Avg`.

Which argument might it be? What might be *really* wrong? Let's look at the your code (reindented for clarity).

```
proc Avg {} {
    global ns Qmon Qsize Qbw Qlost n1 n2 Avgvals lambda

    set sum 0.0
    set c 1

    set fid [open Qsize.tr r]
    set txt [read $fid]
    close $fid

    foreach {x} $txt {
        set sum [expr {$sum + $x}]
        incr c 1
    }

    set avg [expr $sum/$c]
    puts $Avgvals "$lambda $avg"
}
```

OK, the line that's having the problem is in the `foreach` and it's being used to add the words of `$txt` (i.e., read from the file) as floating point numbers (since `sum` is initialised to `0.0`). Well, since `sum` will continue to hold a floating point number provided all the values to add are numeric, we *must* have the problem that one of the words in the file is not a number. It can't be anything else because the expression itself is in braces, guaranteeing a reliable interpretation at the Tcl level. (The `expr $sum/$c` is not as good, though will behave predictably in Tcl 8.5 and 8.6 where we use custom high-reliability floating point to string converter instead of the somewhat shaky one that comes in the standard C library.)

We can't tell from the information provided what the offending value is; the error trace didn't log it (it doesn't hold *everything* or it would be too unwieldy) and you didn't provide a failing sample. If you're going to debug, you can try changing the code to this:

```
proc Avg {} {
    global ns Qmon Qsize Qbw Qlost n1 n2 Avgvals lambda

    set sum 0.0
    set c 1

    set fid [open Qsize.tr r]
    set txt [read $fid]
    close $fid

    foreach {x} $txt {
        if {[catch {
            set sum [expr {$sum + $x}]
            incr c 1
        }] {
            puts "The value at index #$c ('$x') is not numeric"
        }
    }

    set avg [expr $sum/$c]
    puts $Avgvals "$lambda $avg"
}
```

If it turns out that the problem is that there's extra metasyntax in the file that you're reading from, you *need* to deal with that before summing the values up.

<sup>Your code also has a bug: the “average” will be a bit low because `c` ends up one too large.</sup>